# Posting everything except the excerpt in Jekyll

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

So far I've made a custom excerpt in my config.yml file: `excerpt_separator: <!--more-->`

When I write a post I'd like to show the excerpt on the listings page which works just fine. However, I'd like to know if it's possible, on the post page, to post everything that is **not** the excerpt.

Example article:

```
---
title: Lorem ipsum dolor
layout: post
---
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Cras in malesuada ipsum. Vivamus sapien orci, vulputate vitae 
consectetur ut, ullamcorper nec quam. Aliquam erat volutpat.

<!--more-->

Cras lacinia vehicula gravida. Cras sem quam, tincidunt at fringilla
sed, venenatis quis mauris. Praesent sit amet arcu varius mi sodales ultrices.
```

On the post page I'd only like to show the paragraph beginning with "Cras lacinia", not Lorem ipsum.

Is that possible in Jekyll? I've searched and searched and only found ways to customize the excerpt but not to remove it all together.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just replace the `{{ content }}` by a tag that removes the `{{ post.excerpt }}` from the `{{ post.content }}`

```
{{ post.content | remove: post.excerpt }}
```

This will print the `content` without the `excerpt`.
Et hop !

Comment: Wow. That is incredibly simple. Thank you.

Edit: Still not enough rep to up vote but I selected yours as the answer.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Hi there, how can I use it with collections? {{ page.content | remove: page.excerpt }} doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is old, but the accepted answer didn't work for me... I think because in my instance, page.content and page.excerpt were already rendered from Markdown to HTML, and the tags and whitespace didn't match up exactly.

My solution is below for anyone else who comes looking. It splits the post content into an array containing [excerpt, remainder]:

```
{% assign content_array = page.content | split: site.excerpt_separator %}
{% assign excerpt_only = content_array | first %}
{% assign content_remainder = content_array | last %}
```

This requires you to have defined `site.excerpt_separator` in `_config.yml`, but for this usecase you probably have anyway. Now in your template you can simply refer to the variables as needed:

```
<div class="post-excerpt">
  {{ excerpt_only | append: '</p>'}}
</div>

<div class="post-content">
  {{ content_remainder | remove_first: '</p>'}}
</div>
```

The `append:` and `remove_first:` filters are to make the resulting HTML well-formed again. Examine your output and adjust as needed.